# Web page content not shownig after JQuery loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

Above code generate HTML table using `JSON` output.

But, my problem is, after this `JQuery` runs, other page content is not shown.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var html = '<table class="table table-striped">';
    html += '<tr>';
    var flag = 0;

    var data2   =   <?php echo $data; ?>;
    $.each(data2[0], function(index, value){
        html += '<th>'+index+'</th>';
    });
    html += '</tr>';
     $.each(data2, function(index, value){
         html += '<tr>';
        $.each(value, function(index2, value2){
            html += '<td>'+value2+'</td>';
        });
        html += '<tr>';
     });
     html += '</table>';
     $('body').html(html);
     console.log(html);
});
</script>
```

when the page loads, content should disappear and it should shows particular table only.

Comment: It is because you are basically replacing all content of your body to this table, see your code $('body').html(html).

Comment: you mentioned this, `content should disappear and it should shows particular table only`. according to what you have mentioned, your code is doing exactly the same thing. It replaces all contents in the body(i.e., **Everything** in the page) with the table that you have built in this script! Now whats the problem?

Comment: @PrashanthBenny ok then what i need to do, how can i generate table with other table content

Comment: you could append the new table to the one that you have already!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this

```
$('body').html(html);
```

with

```
$('body').append(html);
```

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably cause is

```
$('body').html(html);
```

Because html() method will change the content of body elements. You should use

```
$('body').append(html);
```

to insert content at the end of body elements.

Answer (score -1):

you miss : `html += '</tr>';`
please check with full code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var html = '<table class="table table-striped">';
    html += '<tr>';
    var flag = 0;

    var data2   =   <?php echo $data; ?>;
    $.each(data2[0], function(index, value){
        html += '<th>'+index+'</th>';
    });
    html += '</tr>';
     $.each(data2, function(index, value){
         html += '<tr>';
        $.each(value, function(index2, value2){
            html += '<td>'+value2+'</td>';
        });
        html += '</tr>';
     });
     html += '</table>';
     $('body').html(html);
     console.log(html);
});
</script>
```

Comment: how's that gonna solve this problem when he is replacing whole html into body.html(html). Look carefully what he want..

Comment: please look code carefully he is not complete 'tr' tag and create new 'tr' tag

Comment: buddy his problem states that he want to display this table with existing content. obviously not completing tr will not restrict js from display of table. this aesthetic changes can be tackled once main solution if found. your code will not solve his basic problem which he mean to be answered here.. Hope you get it..